# What was the spoken language in Dwaprar Yuga and earlier Yugas ? Was it Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit, language

Sanskrit is devbhasa i.e. language of gods.  In recorded  history of Kaliyuga , Sanskrit was perhaps never ever communication language of common people. It was mostly used for religious purpose only.

I want to know if sanskrit was language of communication of people in Dwapar Yuga and earlier Yugas ?

Histoical texts like Purans and Ithiahas (Mbh and Ramayan) are written in poetry style and thus it doesn't tell the exact way in which communication occured between people as people don't communicate in peoms but in sentences.